# I have a problem in saving file with the FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string x = "Name: " + label1.Text + " " + "FamilyName: " + label2.Text + " " + "FatherName: " + label3.Text + " " + "PhoneNumber: " + label4.Text;


        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + label1.Text + ".txt", x);
                                    
                MessageBox.Show("The file registered.");
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + label1.Text + ".doc", x);

                MessageBox.Show("The file registered.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose one of the formats.");
            }

        }
    }
```

And this is for store some information from labels in a file, and dynamically selects the file name from `label1`. Then I put a radio button to choose between saving the file in txt format or doc format. After selecting one of the formats and clicking on the Save button, the `folderBrowserDialog` opens so I can choose the path I want to save my file there. But when I chose my path, let's say that I chose this path: 'G:\SavingFile\TextFiles', instead of saving the file in the TextFiles folder, saves it in the SavingFile folder.

My question is why it doesn't save the file in the last folder? And how can I fix it?

Comment: As a note, you're not saving that text in two *different formats*, you're saving the same exact text format in files with two different extensions.

Answer (score 4):

You should not concatenate your paths as string but use [System.IO.Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead. as this will also take care of the correct path-separators, which are missing from your code as `SelectedPath` does not end with a path-separator

So in your case

```
var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, label1.Text +  ".txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, ....);
```

This will take care of the required path separators.

If you are using .Net Core you might also use [System.IO.Path.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.join). But be aware there are some differences in the behaviour of these two methods with regards to rooting the resulting path. See the linked docs for details.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way to save my files that is easier than the way that I did above. I can simply use `saveFileDialog`.

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, x);
}
```